# How to find LatLng bound for an area in google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

In `google maps` I want to fix my camera to a particular country. I don't need whole worlds **Mercator** projection. So I need to set `LatLngBounds` in my google maps. How can I find `LatLngBounds` of a particular region?
Here is my code but it's not setting `LatLngBounds` as my expectation set's constraints on right side.

```java
         LatLng v1= new LatLng(24.044982389517603,89.75482430309057);
         LatLng v2 = new LatLng(22.309956868003045,91.20187237858772);
        LatLngBounds BANGLADESH = new LatLngBounds(
                v2,v1
        );
        mMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(BANGLADESH);
```

[image]

Comment: Country bounding boxes: https://gist.github.com/graydon/11198540 .  (in lng/lat format)

Answer (score 0):

You can get country boundaries once from [openstreetmap.org](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=7/24.365/86.671) like described in [this](https://peteris.rocks/blog/openstreetmap-administrative-boundaries-in-geojson/) article of [Pēteris Ņikiforovs](https://peteris.rocks/) or by http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/get_poly.py?id=184640&params=0 and add it as polygon points find `LatLngBounds` like you do it:

```
...
Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder(); 
for(int i = 0 ; i < N_POINTS; i++) {          
    builder.include(new LatLng(lat, lng));
}
LatLngBounds BANGLADESH = new LatLngBounds = builder.build();

int padding = 15; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(BANGLADESH, padding);

mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate );
...
```